# Assign jPlayer volume to custom button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I have a modified player in my page which uses jPlayer and i want to bind a custom wheel button to the volume function:

[The player page](http://www.tranceil.fm/player2)

```
$musicPlayer.jPlayer({
                            swfPath: "js/jplayer/",
                            solution: 'flash,html',
                            supplied: 'm4a, oga, mp3',
                            preload: 'metadata',
                            volume: 0.8,
                            muted: false,
                            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_N",
                            cssSelector: {
                                play: '.jp-play',
                                pause: '.jp-pause',
                                seekBar: '.jp-seek-bar',
                                playBar: '.jp-play-bar',
                            },
                            errorAlerts: false,
                            warningAlerts: false,
                            ready: function () {
                              $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                                mp3: $first_song,
                                solution: 'flash, html',
                              });
                            },
                        }).bind($.jPlayer.event.ended, function(event){
                            var $o = $('.selected').next('li'),$json = $.parseJSON($o.find('img').attr('data-src'));
                            if(!$o.is(':last')){
                                playSong($o,$json);
                            }
                        });

                });
```

The custom volume wheel:

```
//js code for the metal style wheel - below

        $('#metal .indicator-cw').bind('touchmove', function(event){
            updateMetal();
        });
        $("#metal .indicator-cw").mousemove(updateMetal);

        function updateMetal(){
    var number = $("#metal .result-cw").text();
    var Degrees = parseInt(number);

    $("#rotateit").css({'transform':'rotate(' + (Degrees) + 'deg)', '-webkit-transform':'rotate(' + (Degrees) + 'deg)', '-o-transform':'rotate(' + (Degrees) + 'deg)', '-moz-transform':'rotate(' + (Degrees) + 'deg)', '-ms-transform':'rotate(' + (Degrees) + 'deg)' });

        }
        //js code for the metal style wheel - above
```

HTML:

```
<div id="metal">
        <div class="result-cw"></div>
        <div class="indicator-cw1"><img src="img/metal_indicator.png" id="rotateit" class="indicator-cw-img" /></div>
        <div class="indicator-cw"></div>
    </div>
```

How can i assign the jPlayer volume to that wheel button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [jPlayer documentation](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-volume) you can read that jPlayer's API has a function for volume handling.

All you have to do is translate the degrees of rotation to a number between 0 and 1. Since 360 degrees is the maximum value, all you have to do is to multiply the current degrees of rotation by (1/360) and pass that as a parameter to the volume method.

In your example, it would be something like:

```
var vol = parseInt($("#metal .result-cw").text()) * (1/360);    
$("#player").jPlayer("volume", vol);
```

Comment: Thanx for the help m8, the volume indeed attached to the button, but it wont act normally, if you turn it clock wise it will increase but still rotate if you turn it ccwise..->www.tranceil.fm/player2

Comment: It won't work since $musicPlayer is not accessible in the scope where you are trying to use that variable. I've updated the code, I think that should work.

Comment: Now the volume is not working...the other code worked..but the spin was continuing...it was just a matter of where the wheel should stop and start..but i cant seem to nail it

Comment: I think you have some other problems with your code. Depending on the page loading, sometimes the console with output an error telling that there is no jPlayer object for your player. This may be due to the functions that you call before the document is ready.

As for the wheel rotation, just save the previous value in a variable outside `updateMetal()` and update it every time you change volume. Then check if the previous volume is greater than 0.99 (0.98 maybe) and the current volume is greater than the previous one, then just return. You should the opposite for volumes under 0.01

Comment: Thank you for your help..ill try and solve this with your input